# Help me find a side of a quadrilateral given one side and distance between the centers of two circles inscribed in the same quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

For the quadrilateral ABCD it's given that AD=2, $\angle$ABD=$\angle$ACD=90$^\circ$. The distance between the centers of the inscribed circles in $_\triangle$ABD and $_\triangle$ACD is $\sqrt{2}$. Find the length of BC.

Comment: I would think the quadrilateral should be $ABDC$ or $ACBD$ but $ABCD$ is not possible, as it seems that $AD$ is a diagonal, not a side.

Comment: Well in this problem AD is actually a side of the quadrilateral. It's easy to prove that AD is the diameter of the circumscribed circle of ABCD. I am stuck with the further solution.

Comment: @gt6989b: there is nothing wrong with the given constraints, have a look at the picture below (with $C\equiv C_2$).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see, i interpreted both given angles to be actual angles of the quadrilateral...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question.
[image]

The constraints $\widehat{ABD}=\widehat{ACD}=90^\circ$ give that both $B$ and $C$ lie on the circle with diameter $AD$. Assuming that both $B$ and $C$ lie on the same side of $AD$, it follows (by angle chasing) that both the incenter $I_B$ of $ABD$ and the incenter $I_C$ of $ACD$ lie on the arc of circle through $A$ and $D$ having center at $P$ (defined as the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AD$ with the circumcircle of $ABD$, in such a way that $P$ and $B$ lie on opposite sides of $AD$). Since $AP=\sqrt{2}$, the constraint $I_B I_C=\sqrt{2}$ implies that $\widehat{I_B P I_C}=60^\circ$. On the other hand both $BI_B$ and $CI_C$ go through $P$, hence $\widehat{BPC}=60^\circ$ and the length of $BC$ is given by $\sqrt{3}$ times the circumradius of $ABD$.

$$ \boxed{BC=\color{red}{\sqrt{3}}}. $$